# Print all lines after match

Tags: regex, perl, iteration

I'm trying to parse a file with Perl. I want to print all lines after the regex match.

For example, the file is:

```
num_of_dogs,10,#start_reading
num_of_cat,15
num_birds,20
num_of_butterfly,80
.....
```

I want all the lines after the match of `#start_reading`.

I've tried this, but it just prints the next line:

```
while (my $line = <$csv_file>) {
    next unless $line =~ /(.*),#end_of_tc/;
    if ($line =~ /(.*)/){
    print $file = $1;
    }
}
```

The output would look like this:

```
num_of_cats,15
num_of_birds,20
......
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set a flag when the line contains `#start_reading` and only print the line if the flag is true:

```
while (my $line = <$csv_file>) {
    print $line if $start;
    $start ||= $line =~ /#start_reading/;
}
```

And if you want to stop reading after encountering `#stop_reading`:

```
while (my $line = <$csv_file>) {
    print $line if $print;
    $print ||= $line =~ /#start_reading/;
    $print &&= $line !~ /#stop_reading/;
}
```

Comment: `while (<$csv_file>) { print if $start; $start ||= /#start_reading/; }`

Comment: @blhsing the script aint stopping after #stop_reading, it still reads all the way to the bottom... my code 
            `push @loop_reg, $line if  $print;
            $print ||= $line =~ m/#lane_loop_start/;
            $print &&= $line !~ m/#lane_loop_stop/;`

Answer (score 6):

You may also use the flip-flop, (`..`) operator to bypass all the lines from the beginning of the file to the one containing `#start_reading`

```
while (<$fh>) {
    next if 1 .. /#start_reading/;
    print;
}
```

This bypasses the print from line 1 of the file to the line matching `#start_reading`. Then it prints the remaining lines in the file.

Answer (score 3):

```
 perl -ne 's/.+\,#start_reading\s*/next/e; print $_' d
```

by gnu sed, if your data in 'd',

```
 sed -En '/.+,#start_reading/{:s n; $q;p; bs }' d
```

Answer (score 2):

An efficient and clean way to process a file only after a certain point

```
last if /#start_reading/ while <$csv_file>;  # get past that point in file

while (<$csv_file>) { print }                # now work on it
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by below command. The `/xxx/../yyy/` let perl print the text between two matches. In your case, the second match is simply end of file, so use the keyword `EOF`.

```perl
perl -ne 'print if /^match/../EOF/'
```